# USART, SPI or Bit-Bang for the continuous transfer of bytes without inserted extra bits

Tags: atmega328, spi, uart

I have heard that

1. The SPI hardware introduces a 9th, HIGH bit between bytes
2. USART still uses start and stop bits when in synchronous mode

Are both these statements true? Can I modify the built-in SPI library to avoid #1? Or will I have to bit-bang the protocol needed?

Comment: Page 217&220 of Atmel-42735B-ATmega328/P_Datasheet_Complete-11/2016 do not mention an 9th bit and to me it seems highly unlikely. Have you actually tried if it works for you?

Comment: @Paul I've tried it, but it didn't work, but it could be a problem with the actual program. Sucks that no datasheet exists for my use case

Comment: #2 is false. It's basically USART in SPI mode.  #1 Without using clock signal, it's possible there is some pause as you can't write data in advance.

Comment: BTW: what is the use case? Why do you even need this bitstream?

Comment: @KIIV your question is most relevant here, because the question does not make sense. It is a typical http://xyproblem.info/ When it is for the maximum number of bytes per second, then extra bits or bytes can not be the issue. When it is for a communication protocol then there is manchester code. When a byte needs to be transferred without delay, then 8-bit parallel between two arduino boards is possible plus extra interrupt. There are many ways and many solutions if we would know the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are both these statements true?

Neither of those statements are true.

SPI never inserts extra bits. That would break everything if it did. What you are probably seeing (or think you are seeing) is a delay between bytes being sent. That delay is irrelevant, since the data is only ever sampled on an edge of the clock signal (which edge depends on the mode of the SPI communication) and with no clock edge in that delay period there is no data.

USART in synchronous mode is SPI. There are no start or stop bits in synchronous mode, since the clock is used to synchronise the communication rather than needing start or stop bits.

Answer (score 1):

The SPI peripheral on the ATMega328 cannot continuously send data without a brief pause after every byte, as it does not sample the input buffer immediately after clocking the last bit, no matter what settings are used. At best, you can clock out bytes at the speed you expect +2 clocks when using assembler. The UART does allow continuous streaming of data, and should be used for maximum speed if you do not also need the clock signal. I have tested this with cycle-counted code, setting the SPI peripheral to 8Mhz (its maximum speed with a 16Mhz crystal, as the Arduino UNO uses). With the UART, using a 16 cycle loop in ASM, it's possible to load it with data continuously (I have used this to generate composite video). With the SPI peripheral, you need to add 2 clocks after the peripheral finishes, before it can load the next byte. So at 8Mhz, you can load data into it every 18 clock cycles. This is why it may appear to be clocking out 9 bits instead of 8, if you don't take account of the clock signal.